# Mostrar queryset en template django

Tags: django

Tengo una duda por favor alguien que me pueda orientar , estoy creando un sistema de afiliaciones en Django

Tengo un queryset que me muestra los servicios que tiene un afiliado: lo quiero saber es como hacer que me muestre los tipos de servicios de un afiliado al darle click a su nombre en la misma pagina de Lista de Afiliados.

```
serv = TipoServicio.objects.filter(afiliado__id=5)
<QuerySet [<TipoServicio: EPS >, <TipoServicio: ARL >, <TipoServicio: Caja de Compensación >, <TipoServicio: Pensión >, <TipoServicio: Probefam >]>
```

estas son mis 2 tablas

```
class TipoServicio(models.Model):
Nombre = models.CharField(max_length=50)
Valor = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null = True)

def __str__(self):
    cadena = "{0} "
    return cadena.format(self.Nombre) 

class Afiliado(models.Model):    
Nombre = models.CharField(max_length=50)
Apellido = models.CharField(max_length=50)
Sexo = models.CharField(max_length=12, blank=True, choices=(('M', 'Masculino'), ('F', 'Femenino'),))
tipoDoc = models.ForeignKey(TipoDocumento, blank=True, null = True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)      
Documento = models.CharField(max_length=50)
rango = models.ForeignKey(TipoRango, blank=True, null = True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)     
servicios = models.ManyToManyField(TipoServicio, blank=True, help_text="Ctrl para elegir varios Servicios") 
ciudad = models.ForeignKey(TipoCiudad, blank=True, null = True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
departamento = models.ForeignKey(TipoDepartamento, blank=True, null = True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)     
Distrito = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
Direccion = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)    
Prefijo = models.CharField(default = 57, max_length=200, blank=True)
Telefonos = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)   
Email = models.EmailField(max_length=50, blank=True)
Estatus = models.CharField(max_length=12,  blank=True, default=1, choices=(('1', 'Activo'), ('2', 'Retirado'),))    

def __str__(self):
    cadena = "{0} {1}: ({2})  {3}  "
    return cadena.format(self.Nombre, self.Apellido, self.Documento, self.Telefonos)
```

Esta es mi Vista:

```
class AfiliadoList(ListView):
model = Afiliado
template_name = 'templates/afiliado/lista_afiliados.html'
def get_queryset(self):
    return Afiliado.objects.order_by('-Nombre')
```

Mi template:

```
<tbody>
```

{% if object_list %}

```
  {% for afiliado in object_list %}
  <tr> 
    <td><a href="#{{afiliado.Documento}}" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="collapse">{{ afiliado.Nombre }} {{ afiliado.Apellido }}</a>
      <div id="{{afiliado.Documento}}" class="collapse">
          Servicios:            
      </div>         

    </td>
    <td>{{ afiliado.Prefijo }}+ {{ afiliado.Telefonos }}</td>
    <td>{{ afiliado.rango }}</td> 
    <td>{{ afiliado.ciudad }}</td> 
    <td>{{ afiliado.departamento }}</td>
```

Urls:

```
  path('', AfiliadoList.as_view(), name='index_afiliado'),
path('index', AfiliadoList.as_view(), name='index_afiliado'),



path('agregar/', AfiliadoCreate.as_view(), name='agregar_afiliado'),  
path('<int:pk>/editar/', AfiliadoEdit.as_view(),  name='editar_afiliado'),
path('<int:pk>/eliminar/' , AfiliadoDelete.as_view(),  name='eliminar_afiliado'),
]
```

[image: Template]

[image: Template desplegado]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La relacion **ManyToMany** la puedes mostrar de dos formas:

```
{% for afiliado in object_list %}
{{ afiliado.rango }}
{{ afiliado.ciudad }}
..
..
  {% for servicio in afiliado.servicios %}
   {{ servicio }}
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

mediate un ciclo for o en su defecto con un join:

```
  {% for afiliado in object_list %}
    {{ afiliado.rango }}
    {{ afiliado.ciudad }}
    {{ afiliado.servicios.all|join: ',' }}
 {% endfor %}
```

[Django template join](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/templates/builtins/#join)
Espero te sirva..!!

Comment: Amigo muchísimas gracias de verdad fue muy útil tu respuesta, me sirvió de mucho termine utilizando        {{afiliado.servicios.all|join: ',' }} y efectivamente me muestra todos los servicios que tiene asociado un afiliado!!

Comment: de nada tambien me tomo mi tiempo saber como mostrar dichas relaciones, si te sirvio ayudaria mucho que selecciones como respuesta correcta para futuras referencias..!! @IlanJoseGraterol